# How to solve $(107 + (107 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

As the title says, I'm trying to solve the following equation: $(107 + (107 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}} = x$

Besides the straightforward statement, I've had some difficulties while trying to solve it, and I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

The problem comes from [here](http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/Coffins/coffinsmain.html) (problem n. 8) and it has a quite sad story behind (you can read more about it [here](http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/coffins.html)).

Comment: I know exactly what you mean by sad stories. There are many students that work really hard to grasp difficult material while others simply post their homework to websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $y = \sqrt{x+107} \implies x = \sqrt{107+y}\implies x-y = \sqrt{y+107}-\sqrt{x+107}= -\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt{x+107}+\sqrt{y+107}}\implies (x-y)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+107}+\sqrt{y+107}}\right)=0 \implies x = y \implies x = \sqrt{x+107}\implies x^2-x-107=0\implies x = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{429}}{2}\implies x = y=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{429}}{2}$ since $x > 0, y > 0$.

Comment: This seems like it has some formatting problems...

Answer (score -1):

$x= \sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+x}} , x>0$. Substitute $x= \sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+x}}$ in RHS:

$x = \sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+x}}}} = \sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+\sqrt{107+...}}}} = \sqrt{107+x}$

$x^2=107+x \text{ and } x>0$